# Кэширование действий пользователя

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Есть экран и несколько View-элементов, таких как check-box, switch, seekbar.

Все изменения состояний элементов кэшируются в SharedPreferences. По нажатию "Back" происходит поочередный откат изменений, пока "стэк изменений" не окажется пуст.
Существует таймаут бездействия (скажем 5 секунд), по истечению которого все последние одиночные изменения становятся скоупом - т.е. объединяются в одно действие, которое по нажатию "Back" отменяется разом. Скоупы также имеют свойство накапливаться, т.е. если периодически производить действия и бездействовать по 5 секунд, то по многократному нажатию "Back" мы должны видеть несколько отмен скоупов.

Также есть дополнительное, но не обязательное, требование:

Реализовать масштабируемое решение для условий, когда мы не знаем заранее, сколько будет элементов пользовательского ввода

Помогите реализовать это, пожалуйста. Не обязательно кодом, любая подсказка будет очень кстати.

Comment: А цель - для чего вы все это делаете? Можно узнать?

Comment: @Barmaley
Я прохожу стажировку, это одна из задач, которую нужно решить.

Comment: Это не есть ответ, важен ответ - для чего это нужно с точки зрения функционала системы или UI